# SAPUI5 - How to get the selected button index of RadioGroupButton

Tags: javascript, controller, sapui5

I'm new to SAPUI5 and trying to get the selected button index of a **RadioGroupButton in SAPUI5**.

The reason for this, is to hide or show more survey questions. And the form is based on two languages so it would be better to get the index rather than the text of the selectedButton.

Here's my code for both XML and controller. Any help is appreciated as I don't why it doesn't recognize the button index in console and shows that it's undefined!

**XML**

```
<VBox class="sapUiMediumMargin">
                        <VBox id="Q1">
                            <Label labelFor="rgb1" text="{i18n>Q1}" />
                            <RadioButtonGroup id="rbg1" columns="2" width="100%">
                                <RadioButton id="RB1-1" text="{i18n>radio.button.no}" select="onSelect"/>
                                <RadioButton id="RB1-2" text="{i18n>radio.button.yes}" select="onSelect"/>
                            </RadioButtonGroup>
                            <!--Small Margin-->
                            <HBox class="sapUiSmallMargin"/>
                        </VBox>
```

**Controller**

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/core/Element",
    "sap/m/MessageToast"
], function(Controller, Element, MessageToast) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("aaaa.comform.controller.view1", {

        onSelect: function() {

            var oRBGroup = this.getView().byId("rbg1");
            var oButtonSelectedIndex = oRBGroup.getSelectedButtonIndex();
            var oVBox1 = this.getView().byId("Q2"); // another Hidden question to be shown if answer is Yes



            if (oButtonSelectedIndex === 1)) {  // 1 means answer is Yes

                oVBox1.setVisible(true);
                // console.log(getSelctedButton);
            } else {
                oVBox1.setVisible(false);
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When select event is fired your handler will be called with Event object. You can read what parameters are available on the `select` event here - https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.RadioButtonGroup%23events/select.
You can make use of the `selectedIndex` parameter.

First in the XML view move the listener to the RadioButtonGroup. This will remove the need to add a listener to every RadioButton in this group.

**XML**

```
<RadioButtonGroup id="rbg1" columns="2" width="100%" select="onSelect">
```

**Controller**

```
onSelect: function (oEvent) {
  var iIndex = oEvent.gatParameter("selectedIndex"),
      oGroup = oEvent.getSource();

  if (iIndex === 1) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }     
}
```